# Зачем нужен 0xDEADBEEF?

Tags: c, c++

Я разбираюсь в программе и вижу объявление

```
unsigned long transfer[TRANSFER_LENGTH] = { 0xDEADBEEF };
```

а ниже по коду

```
for (int i = 0; i < TRANSFER_LENGTH; i++)
    transfer[i] = GetData();
```

Вот зачем присваивать transfer 0xDEADBEEF, а не взять просто 0?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Потому что DEADBEEF прекрасно видно в hex-dump'е как осмысленная константа 0xDEADBEEF. Вот представьте себе, что Вы анализируете лог обмена и видите там 00000000. Неясно - была передача данных или нет. И что нули означают. А когда получается DEADBEEF понятно, что что-то произошло нехорошее и в каком конкретно месте нужно искать причину. Еще раз поясню, что при нормальном исполнении программы вероятностью увидеть DEADBEEF (или любую другую аналогичную) константу равна 0. А нолей в памяти бывает сколько угодно. Вот на этом игра и ведется.

PS: еще обращу внимание на два момента:

- DEADBEEF по-английски означает 'дохлое мясо' :-)
- константа DEADBEEF одинаково записывается как строчка и как байты в hex-представлении

Comment: Да, в hex-dump'ах ковыряются настоящие панки. :))

Comment: Ой, я это столько раз встречал в хексах, а нинал, просто так получилось или кто-то специально обозвал =D